# Iam unable to get the ALB URL.. The address is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

Iam trying to follow this guide
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-alb-ingress-controller-with-amazon-eks-on-fargate/

Steps below:

```
Cluster provisioning
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
CLUSTER_NAME=eks-fargate-alb-demo

eksctl create cluster --name $CLUSTER_NAME --region $AWS_REGION --fargate

kubectl get svc
You should get the following response:
NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE
kubernetes ClusterIP 10.100.0.1 <none> 443/TCP 16h

Set up OIDC provider with the cluster and create the IAM policy used by the ALB Ingress Controller
wget -O alb-ingress-iam-policy.json https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/master/docs/examples/iam-policy.json
aws iam create-policy --policy-name ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy --policy-document file://alb-ingress-iam-policy.json

STACK_NAME=eksctl-$CLUSTER_NAME-cluster
VPC_ID=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name "$STACK_NAME" | jq -r '[.Stacks[0].Outputs[] | {key: .OutputKey, value: .OutputValue}] | from_entries' | jq -r '.VPC')
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity | jq -r '.Account')


cat > rbac-role.yaml <<-EOF
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - events
      - ingresses
      - ingresses/status
      - services
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
      - services
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: alb-ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: alb-ingress-controller
    namespace: kube-system
EOF

kubectl apply -f rbac-role.yaml
These commands will create two resources for us and the output should be similar to this:

 

clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/alb-ingress-controller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/alb-ingress-controller created
And finally the Kubernetes Service Account:

eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
--name alb-ingress-controller \
--namespace kube-system \
--cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
--attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:policy/ALBIngressControllerIAMPolicy \
--approve
This eksctl command will deploy a new CloudFormation stack with an IAM role. Wait for it to finish before keep executing the next steps.

 

Deploy the ALB Ingress Controller
Let’s now deploy the ALB Ingress Controller to our cluster:


cat > alb-ingress-controller.yaml <<-EOF
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alb-ingress-controller
        args:
        - --ingress-class=alb
        - --cluster-name=$CLUSTER_NAME
        - --aws-vpc-id=$VPC_ID
        - --aws-region=$AWS_REGION
          image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.4
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress-controller
EOF
kubectl apply -f alb-ingress-controller.yaml
 

Deploy sample application to the cluster
Now that we have our ingress controller running, we can deploy the application to the cluster and create an ingress resource to expose it.

Let’s start with a deployment:

cat > nginx-deployment.yaml <<-EOF
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "nginx-deployment"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "nginx"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: "nginx"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
EOF

kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
The output should be similar to:

deployment.apps/alb-ingress-controller created
Then, let’s create a service so we can expose the NGINX pods:

cat > nginx-service.yaml <<-EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  name: "nginx-service"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    type: NodePort
    selector:
      app: "nginx"
EOF

kubectl apply -f nginx-service.yaml
The output will be similar to:

deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment created
Finally, let’s create our ingress resource:

**cat > nginx-ingress.yaml <<-EOF**
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "nginx-ingress"
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: "nginx-service"
            servicePort: 80
EOF
kubectl apply -f nginx-ingress.yaml

The output will be:

ingress.extensions/nginx-ingress created
Once everything is done, you will be able to get the ALB URL by running the following command:

kubectl get ingress nginx-ingress
The output of this command will be similar to this one:

NAME HOSTS ADDRESS PORTS AGE
nginx-ingress * **5e07dbe1-default-ngnxingr-2e9-113757324.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com** 80 9s
```

but Iam unable to get the ALB URL in this step
kubectl get ingress nginx-ingress

Any help?

Comment: Please include a lot more detail on what you tried, what happened, and what you're expecting. It's very hard to figure out what went wrong without any details.

Comment: Hi did you get the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by updating `alb-ingress-controller.yaml`. I replaced `$CLUSTER_NAME`, `$VPC_ID` and `$AWS_REGION` by their value.